# В докере depends_on не устанавливает порядок запуска служб

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Я изучаю микросервисную архитектуру по книге "Микросервисы Spring в действии". Дошел до страниц, где два микросервиса упаковываются в докер. Один микросервис - служба лицензий, и второй миросервис - служба конфигураций, которая предоставляет конфиги для запуска службы лицензий в разном окружении. По логике сначала должен стартовать служба конфига, и только когда она уже работает, должен запускаться микросервис лицензий. Но это не работает, директива depends_on почему-то не устанавливает порядок запуска сервисов.

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  configserver:
    image: ostock/config-server:1.0
    ports:
      - "8071:8071"
    environment:
      ENCRYPT_KEY: "fje83Ki8403Iod87dne7Yjsl3THueh48jfuO9j4U2hf64Lo"
    networks:
      backend:
        aliases:
          - "configserver"

  licensingservice:
    image: ostock/licensing-service:1.0
    environment:
      PROFILE: "dev"
      CONFIGSERVER_URI: "http://configserver:8071"
      CONFIGSERVER_PORT:   "8071"
      DATABASESERVER_PORT: "5432"
      ENCRYPT_KEY:       "IMSYMMETRIC"
    depends_on:
      configserver:
        condition: service_started
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    networks:
      - backend

networks:
  backend:
    driver: bridge
```

Как правильно сконфигурировать docker-compose, чтобы службы запускались в правильном порадке (сначала конфиг, потом лицензии)?

**Обновление**. Добавил healthcheck в конфиг сервиса конфигурации

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  configserver:
    image: ostock/config-server:1.0
    ports:
      - "8071:8071"
    environment:
      ENCRYPT_KEY: "fje83Ki8403Iod87dne7Yjsl3THueh48jfuO9j4U2hf64Lo"
    healthcheck:
      test: "curl --fail --silent localhost:8071/actuator/health | grep UP || exit 1"
      interval: 20s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 40s
    networks:
      backend:
        aliases:
          - "configserver"

  licensingservice:
    image: ostock/licensing-service:1.0
    environment:
      PROFILE: "dev"
      CONFIGSERVER_URI: "http://configserver:8071"
      CONFIGSERVER_PORT:   "8071"
      DATABASESERVER_PORT: "5432"
      ENCRYPT_KEY:       "IMSYMMETRIC"
    depends_on:
      configserver:
        condition: service_healthy
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    networks:
      - backend

networks:
  backend:
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/
То что сервис **запустился** не значит что он готов принимать запросы и штатно работать. Вам нужно настроить `healthcheck` и использовать `service_healthy` вместо `service_started`

Comment: Я обновил первый пост. Добавил в конфиг проверку healthcheck сервиса конфигураций, но теперь служба лицензий вообще не запускается - пишет, что сервис конфига unhealthy. Почему не работает healthcheck?

Comment: Вы уверены что ваш healthcheck корректен? Если запустить конфиг сервер без лицензионного сервера и попробовать ваш healthcheck, он сработает как надо?